# Expectation of the derivative of a random process

Tags: probability, integration, derivatives, random-variables, expectation

Let's have a Random Process $Y(t) = X(t) + 0.3 X'(t)$

Mean of $X(t) = 5t$

> Question : Find the mean function of $Y(t)$
>
> What I did : $E(Y) = E(X) + 0.3\cdot E(X')$ ?

I don't know if I have to take the derivative out of the expectation and if yes, then why (what are the cases where I can do it)?

Comment: Write $X'(t)$ as $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{X(t+h)-X(t)}{h}$ and worry only about when to exchange the limit with the expectation (an integral).

Comment: @user192614 Do i need to compute the integral according to the distribution of X(t+h) or X(t), i don;t really know how to write the expectation

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $X$ is m.s. differentiable. Then for any $t$ fixed,
$$
\frac{X(s)-X(t)}{s-t}\to_{m.s.}X'(t)\quad \text{as }s\to t 
$$
It thus follows that
$$
\frac{\mu_X(s)-\mu_X(t)}{s-t}\to_{m.s.}\mu_{X'}(t)\quad \text{as }s\to t \tag 1
$$
because the limit of the means is the mean of the limit, for a m.s. convergent sequence (in fact if $X_n\to_{m.s.}X$ then $\mathbb{E}(X_n)\to_{m.s.}\mathbb{E}(X)$)

But (1) is just the definition of the statement that the derivative of $\mu_X$ at $t$ is equal to $\mu_{X'}(t)$.That is,$\frac{d X}{dt}(t) =\mu_{X'}(t)$ for all $t$, or more concisely, $\mu'_X(t)=\mu_{X'}(t)$

So you have
$$\mathbb{E}(Y)=\mu_X+\mu_X'=5t+\frac{3}{2}$$